# Jquery $.ajax causes Browser freeze for a second

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a $ajax function that goes out to a URL and gets multiple json objects which I make into divs. I have about 50 objects, and am calling the $ajax function with setInterval every 10 seconds so that it can get updates for each of the json objects I make into divs. I notice that every time the $ajax function is executed, the browser freezes for a second or two. How do I minimize/eliminate the freezing or is there a better approach to what I am trying to do?

Comment: show some actual code, but it sounds like you are flagging it to perform a synchronous call instead of asynchronous call

Answer (score 0):

Dom manipulations can cause the browser to freeze. Try to return the div that you want to update rather than just the data so that all you are doing is replacing the current node. The idea is to minimalize the dom interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous calls will not "freeze" the browser. If you have already checked that you are executing your AJAX call asynchronously (the default method), you should check the process that converts your JSON responses into divs. This process is not asynchronous, and may block other operations.

Answer (score 0):

We should really look at your code, if you want to post it, to look for anything strange, but it's possible you're running into one of the following issues:

- [Freezes only happen locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505840/jquery-load-freezing-the-page), but works when you deploy it live
- [IE-specific issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757153/ie6-7-freezing-during-jquery-ajax-request) due to DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

$ajax is probably not what is causing your freezing. $ajax calls back to your web server asynchronously so it shouldn’t block your browser. If you are recreating your 50 objects every call this would definitely cause a freezing affect. Only update the view if it has changes.

As for a better way I would recommend using a library such as backbone.js to handle refreshing your view layer for you.